# beforeunload event does not work in IE 10

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, dom-events, internet-explorer-10

I am using AngularJS and I want to save some variables to my database before leaving the controller's scope, I do this using:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    $scope.saveTableOptions($scope.usersTableOptions);
});
```

It works fine, but on refresh the scope is lost and the changes are not saved. To tackle this issue I used following in addition:

```
$window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    $scope.saveTableOptions($scope.usersTableOptions);
});
```

It works fine in all browsers except IE 10. I tried many different things like using jQuery or JavaScript window events, but nothing seems to work, is there any workaround for that?